# remove duplicate key value from array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const response = [
      { en: "abc", fr: "def" },
      { en: "xyz", fr: "xyz" },
      { en: "abc", fr: "abc" },
      { en: "xyz", fr: "pwe" },
    ];
```

Remove 2nd and 3rd object from array

Expected Output:

```
const res = [
      { en: "abc", fr: "def" },
      { en: "xyz", fr: "pwe" },
    ];
```

Comment: Why the second `en: "abc"` but the first `en: "xyz"`?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @adiga I don't think the duplicate is very well chosen. This question is about removing objects with identical values for different keys. There is no comparison being done between the objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `filter()` them out:

```js
const response = [
  { en: "abc", fr: "def" },
  { en: "xyz", fr: "xyz" },
  { en: "abc", fr: "abc" },
  { en: "xyz", fr: "pwe" },
];

const result = response.filter(({en, fr}) => en !== fr);

console.log(result);
```